# Make a part of url as ellipse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to show a part of url link as ellipse and when I click the ellipse it should show the entire url. Using selected I'm only showing the final li and I'm not showing the 1st two li's. Not sure how to get the `selectedClass` url from below code.

That means the url "/home/digital/photos" should show like "/home/.../photos. And I'm only trying to do it in mobile.

```html
<div class="url">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/digital">Components</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/digital/photos" class="selected">photos</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: So, you want when the user hovers over a link for it to show only part of the url?

Answer (score 0):

You could do. Ive seen this done, a few times. But essentially if you want this for all your A hrefs you may need to set some sort of global click.  But this should get you going.

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.location.href='https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/css-masonry-grid-gallery-2/';">Home</a>
```